# Частица ТАКИ

Tags: орфография, частица

"Таки" с именами пишется через дефис или нет?
Пишу в ворде "Маша таки задала этот вопрос", а ворд выделяет ошибку и говорит, что нужно писать через дефис.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Частица ТАКИ после **глагола или наречия** пишется через **дефис**. Через **дефис** пишется и слово **всё-таки.**

С **существительными и местоимениями** ТАКИ пишется **раздельно**. ***Это Ваш случай.***